# Using Prometheus metrics with CircuitBreakerConfigCustomizer

Tags: resilience4j

I'm trying to setup prometheus metrics with CircuitBreaker, our application uses *CircuitBreakerConfigCustomizer* with an entry in application.properties as outlined in https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3

Since its a customizer, we need an entry in application.properties to set `resilience4j.circuitbreaker.backends.backendA.register-health-indicator=true` where **backendA** is the circuit breaker name.

Probably, this is associating the CB backendA with some registry. However, I want to retrieve this registry so that I can use `TaggedCircuitBreakerMetrics.ofCircuitBreakerRegistry` and bind it to a `PrometheusMeterRegistry` - but how can I fetch the associated registry?

I created a new registry using *ofDefaults()* but that is a different instance and doesn't have references to the backends already defined in properties.

How do I setup metrics to work with this setup?

Comment: Are you using micrometer?

Comment: Yes, I include micrometer-prometheus dependency to use PrometheusMeterRegistry

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using micrometer, resilience4j provides a micrometer module so that the metrics would be exported out of the box.

Check the documentation for details [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/micrometer)

Comment: That was the documentation I followed, hence why I mention using TaggedCircuitBreakerMetrics as well - but for it to work, the right CircuitBreakerRegistry needs to be linked and I can't get that when declaratively defining the CBs in application.properties

Comment: According to the docs, for prometheus you need only to add the dependency https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/micrometer#prometheus